# How to only accept a specific colour in a prompt field from inside an array

Tags: javascript

I am making a colour guessing game which will let the user choose a colour from an array.

It will then change the page colour to the colour once they've correctly guessed it.

However, the input will accept random letters that aren't in the array.

How can I add a function to only accept letters that are stored in the array.

Below is my code:

```
var array = [
  "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green", "black", "cyan", "purple", "silver", 
  "orange", "lime", "magenta", "olive", "maroon", "brown", "darkblue", "lightblue"
];
array = array.sort();
var guess_input;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;
alert(target);

function do_game() {
  var target_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length - 0)) + 0;
  var target = array[target_index];
  var message = "I am thinking of one of these array:\n\n";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    message += array[i];
    if (i == (array.length - 2)) {
      message += " and ";
    } else if (i != (array.length - 1)) {
      message += ", ";
    }
  }
  while (!finished) {
    guess_input = prompt(message).toLowerCase();
    guesses++;
    finished = check_guess(guess_input, target);
    if (finished) {
      var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      myBody.style.background = target;
    }
  }
  var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  myBody.style.background = target;
}

function check_guess(guesses, target) {
  if (array.indexOf(guesses) < 0) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var color = "";
var colors = ["blue", "gray", "yellow"];
while(colors.indexOf(color) < 0) 
  color=prompt("Please enter a valid color: "+colors.join(', '));
alert('Your chosen color is: '+color);
```

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. is there a way to do this without having an alert/prompt show?

Comment: of course, but your question specifically asked for a prompt.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once. Sorry, I meant there would be one initial prompt explaining the instructions, but none theiradfter.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with Window.prompt as this is a browser implemented mechanism that is very limited.

Can you use an input field and validate on keyup:

`<input type="text" onkeyup="validateInput(this)" />`

```
function validateInput(e){

  //check that the e.keyCode is one that you permit, return false
}
```